# Where do I find Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 (Full Profile)?

Tags: windows-xp, .net-framework

I tried to install [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (Standalone Installer)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17718) but this isn't the correct version. Where do I find Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 (Full Profile)?

I need this for my Win XP 32bit PC, which isn't able to connect to the internet at the moment.

Comment: Do you have SP3 installed?

Comment: Yes, SP3 is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That file name contains `Full` so it is the full version, you have to do *nothing* else than that.**

For reference, here is how to get the .NET Framework (Client Profile) for Clients:

1. Go to [Microsoft.com/Net](http://microsoft.com/net).
2. Hit the obvious Download .NET Framework button.
3. You'll notice that the file has `Client` in it.

For reference, here is how to get the .NET Framework (Full Install) for Developers:

1. Go to the Microsoft website.
2. Open the Products tab.
3. Click .NET Framework under Developer Tools.
4. Choose either the Stable or the Beta version in the middle.
5. You'll notice that the file has `Full` in it.